# Getting two different student data from a numpy table

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import numpy as np

#Student Names and their grades

names=np.array([['Richard',90],
                ['Lilia',80],
                ['Sisi',95],
                ['John',30],
                ['Michael',100]])


desirednames=names[names[:,0]=='Richard' or names[:,0]=='Lilia']

print(desirednames)
```

Hello, I want to get just the data for Richard and Lilia, but python gives an error 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'. How can I solve this problem without using any special functions, and by just using basic array operators?

Comment: This is just a numpy ndarray not a "table" you should probably just be using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
desired_names = names[np.isin(names[:, 0], ['Richard', 'Lilia'])]
print(desired_names)
```

**Output**

```
[['Richard' '90']
 ['Lilia' '80']]
```

Or a simple logical or:

```
desired_names = names[(names[:, 0] == 'Lilia') | (names[:, 0] == 'Richard')]
```

The `|` operator is the *elementwise* [logical or](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html#numpy.logical_or) the `or` tries to eval the truth value of the array, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for solution but is there any solution without using special functions like isin?

Comment: @blit Updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please tell why python gives error when we write 'or' instead of '|'. I mean, what is the difference between them?

Comment: @blit Updated the answer!

Comment: I guess the elementwise operator for 'and' is '&', am I right? I cannot found on the website.

Comment: @blit Yes it is

Answer (score 1):

just need to change your code like this:

```
desirednames=names[(names[:,0]=='Richard') | (names[:,0]=='Lilia')]
```